# Phonegap file upload works for local server but not for remote server

Tags: php, android, ajax, cordova, file-upload

On Android, I'm using the Phonegap

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();

ft.upload(pic_to_upload, "http://" + app_domain + "/test_phonegap.php/",
          success, failure, options);
```

If I set the domain to localhost or 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.0.6 (internal IP) it works,
but if I use the actual domain of the website it doesn't work.

More specifically what happens is the php script is executed (server is Apache), but if I look at the $_REQUEST or $_FILE variables they are empty, whereas with localhost it receives everything just fine.

I've put into my xml/config.xml:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<access origin="http://www.domain.com/"/>
```

where domain.com is the domain to which I sent the request, again, it does receive the request but without the $_REQUEST or $_FILE variables (also without the $_GET and $_POST, all these variables are empty)

what can be going wrong? I'm completely baffled.

All the other AJAX requests I done were JSONP and worked without a problem, but for file upload it won't work sadly.

Also, I see nothing in Apache's error log from the last week or so there's nothing about this in the error log.

Thanx for any help

Comment: Maybe it's because of _same origin policy_?

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned, this is done on Android from the application after it's been compiled, it might be connected to same origin policy anyway though, but I'm not sure in what way.

Answer (score 0):

add your domain to phonegap/cordova white list unless you add a domain to white list phonegap will cut any attempt to access them for more information :

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html